# @viewChild not working - cannot read property nativeElement of undefined

Tags: angular, viewchild

I'm trying to access a native element in order to focus on it when another element is clicked (much like the html attribute "for" - for cannot be used on elements of this type.

However I get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

I try to console.log the nativeElement in `ngAfterViewInit()` so that it is loaded but it still throws the error.

I also access nativeElement in the click event handler, so that I can focus the element when another element is clicked - is this possibly what is mucking it up, because it compiles before the view has loaded?.

eg:

```ts
ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.keywordsInput.nativeElement); // throws an error
}

focusKeywordsInput(){
    this.keywordsInput.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

full Code:

relevant part of the html template being used:

```ts
<div id="keywords-button" class="form-group" (click)="focusKeywordsInput()">
    <input formControlName="keywords" id="keywords-input" placeholder="KEYWORDS (optional)"/>
    <div class="form-control-icon" id="keywords-icon"></div>
</div>
```

component.ts:

```ts
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import {  REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, 
          FormGroup, 
          FormBuilder, 
          Validators,
          ControlValueAccessor
        } from '@angular/forms';
import { NumberPickerComponent } from './number-picker.component';
import { DistanceUnitsComponent } from './distance-units.component';
import { MapDemoComponent } from '../shared/map-demo.component';
import { AreaComponent } from './area-picker.component';
import { GoComponent } from './go.component';
import { HighlightDirective } from '../highlight.directive';

@Component({
   selector: 'find-form',
   templateUrl: 'app/find-page/find-form.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['app/find-page/find-form.component.css'],
   directives: [REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, 
                NumberPickerComponent, 
                DistanceUnitsComponent, 
                MapDemoComponent, 
                AreaComponent, 
                GoComponent]
})
export class FindFormComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
   findForm: FormGroup;
   submitted: boolean; // keep track on whether form is submitted
   events: any[] = []; // use later to display form changes
   @ViewChild('keywords-input') keywordsInput;
//comment
   constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, el: ElementRef) {}

   ngOnInit() {
      this.findForm = this.formBuilder.group({
         firstname: ['', [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5) ] ],
         lastname: ['', Validators.required],
         keywords: [],
         area: ['', Validators.required],
         address: this.formBuilder.group({
            street: [],
            zip: [],
            city: []
         })
      });

      this.findForm.valueChanges.subscribe(data => console.log('form changes', data));
   }

     ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.keywordsInput.nativeElement); // throws an error
  }

   focusKeywordsInput(){
      this.keywordsInput.nativeElement.focus();
   }

   save(isValid: boolean) {
      this.submitted = true;
      // check if model is valid
      // if valid, call API to save customer
      console.log(isValid);
   }
}
```

full html template (probably irrelevant):

```ts
<form class="text-uppercase" [formGroup]="findForm" (ngSubmit)="save(findForm.value, findForm.valid)">
    <div class="row is-heading">
        <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-lg-4 offset-lg-4 input-group">
            <h2 class="search-filter-heading heading m-x-auto">find vegan</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row has-error-text">
        <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-lg-4 offset-lg-4 input-group btn-group" style="height:64px;">
            <div style="position: relative; display: inline-block; width: 100%;">
                <multiselect #multiselect></multiselect>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row error-text"  [style.display]="multiselect.selectedCategories.length < 1 && submitted ? 'block' : 'none'">
        <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-lg-4 offset-lg-4 form-group input-group btn-group">
            <small>Please select at least 1 category.</small>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row is-heading">
        <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-lg-4 offset-lg-4 input-group">
            <h2 class="search-filter-heading heading m-x-auto">within</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-lg-4 offset-lg-4 input-group btn-group" style="height:64px;">
            <div style="position: relative; display: inline-block;">
                <number-picker #numberPicker></number-picker>
            </div>
            <distance-units></distance-units>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row is-heading">
        <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-lg-4 offset-lg-4 input-group">
            <h2 class="search-filter-heading heading m-x-auto">of</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row has-error-text">
        <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-lg-4 offset-lg-4 input-group btn-group" style="height:64px;">
            <div style="position: relative; display: inline-block; width: 100%;">
                <my-area></my-area>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row error-text"  [style.display]="multiselect.selectedCategories.length < 1 && submitted ? 'block' : 'none'">
        <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-lg-4 offset-lg-4 form-group input-group btn-group">
            <small [hidden]="findForm.controls.firstname.valid || (findForm.controls.firstname.pristine && !submitted)">Please enter an area.</small>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row is-heading">
        <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-lg-4 offset-lg-4 input-group">
            <h2 class="search-filter-heading heading m-x-auto">keywords</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-lg-4 offset-lg-4 input-group btn-group" style="height:64px;">
            <div style="position: relative; display: inline-block; width: 100%;">
                <div id="keywords-button" class="form-group" (click)="focusKeywordsInput()">
                    <input formControlName="keywords" id="keywords-input" placeholder="KEYWORDS (optional)"/>
                    <div class="form-control-icon" id="keywords-icon"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-lg-4 offset-lg-4 input-group btn-group" style="height:64px;">
            <div style="position: relative; display: inline-block; width: 100%;">
                <go></go>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 103, accepted):

`@ViewChild('keywords-input') keywordsInput;` doesn't match `id="keywords-input"`

```ts
id="keywords-input"
```

should be instead a template variable:

```ts
#keywordsInput
```

Note that camel case should be used, since `-` is not allowed in template reference names.

`@ViewChild()` supports names of template variables as string:

```ts
@ViewChild('keywordsInput') keywordsInput;
```

or component or directive types:

```ts
@ViewChild(MyKeywordsInputComponent) keywordsInput;
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/35209681/217408

**Hint:**
`keywordsInput` is not set before `ngAfterViewInit()` is called

Comment: If it is not set before, how do you set it after?

Comment: If you mean `keywordsInput`, then you don't set it yourself, it's set by Angulars change detection.

Comment: using ngAfterViewInit() did the job!

Comment: Hint worked!!! Don't set "keywordsInput" before ngAfterViewInit() is called.

Answer (score 97):

You'll also get this error if your target element is inside a hidden element.  If this is your HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="false">
    <span #sp>Hello World</span>
</div>
```

Your `@ViewChild('sp') sp` will be undefined.

## Solution

In such a case, then don't use `*ngIf`.

Instead use a class to show/hide your element being hidden.

```
<div [class.show]="shouldShow">...</div>
```

Comment: How to access field if its hidden via ng-If ? As viewChild is showing undefined even when ngIf is true.

Comment: @AnilUttani  I don't remember what I did with this example, but can you use `ngShow` instead?

Comment: @user2023861 You can use `[class.show]="showSomething"` or an inverse logic `[class.hide]="!showSomething"`.

Comment: I ran into this when my input element was in a `Material Tab` component, in the tab that was not visible by default (when the parent component loads).  Solved it by moving code from `ngAfterView` to the event handler that runs when the relevant tab becomes active.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm new to Angular this *ngIf explain just saved me

Comment: Im still getting 'Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined' allthough i call it inside ngAfterView and within a timeout. Also tried [class.show], [hidden], etc. but not win. The entire component is routet, can that also affect the result since not every routet component is opened at the start?

Comment: Yes to my previous question in comments: Router-outlet hostet components also effect the availability of viewchilds such as ngIf does. A solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39255311/can-you-use-viewchild-or-similar-with-a-router-outlet-how-if-so)

Comment: I had the same issue, the element was undefined even after calling from ngAfterViewInit, so I have to drop the *ngIf use and look for a different approach to access the element at runtime. I was getting this issue of undefined for <video> element access from angule .ts file.

Comment: Alternative can use `[hidden]="!showSomething"`

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to add if someone want to make the field required, this will not be enough. You should add  this as well.:
   [hidden]="showSomething"
   [required]="!showSomething"

Answer (score 18):

The accepted answer is correct in all means and I stumbled upon this thread after I couldn't get the Google Map render in one of my app components.

Now, if you are on a recent angular version i.e. 7+ of angular then you will have to deal with the following **ViewChild** declaration i.e.

```
@ViewChild(selector: string | Function | Type<any>, opts: {
read?: any;
static: boolean;
})
```

Now, the interesting part is the static value, which by definition says

- static - True to resolve query results before change detection runs

Now for rendering a map, I used the following ,

```
@ViewChild('map', { static: true }) mapElement: any;
  map: google.maps.Map;
```

Comment: I think i am facing what you said, but I keep receiving undefined, how do you reference mapElement?

Comment: @AndresFelipe for my input autocomplete I made like this:
 `@ViewChild('searchAddress', {static: true})
  public address: ElementRef;`
and in html  
`<input  #searchAddress />`
hope it's helpful

Comment: This worked for me. @ViewChild('gantt_here', { static: true })
 ganttContainer!: ElementRef;

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar problem, but in my case I was trying to read the `nativeElement` inside the `ngOnInit` method:

```
@ViewChild('userNameInput') userNameInput: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;
...
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userNameInput.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

I've changed to `ngAfterViewInit` and everything worked fine:

```
@ViewChild('userNameInput') userNameInput: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;
...
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.userNameInput.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 11):

This error occurs when you're trying to target an element that is wrapped in a condition.

So, here if I use ngIf in place of [hidden], it will give me TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

So use [hidden], class.show or class.hide in place of *ngIf.

```
<button (click)="displayMap()" class="btn btn-primary">Display Map</button>

   <div [hidden]="!display">
      <div #mapContainer id="map">Content to render when condition is true.</div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

in my case i just checking undefied

`  @ViewChild('myinput') myInputField: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {

```
if (this.myInputField !== undefined) {
  this.myInputField.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, this error occurs when you're trying to target an element that is wrapped in a condition, for example:
`<div *ngIf="canShow"> <p #target>Targeted Element</p></div>`

In this code, if `canShow` is false on render, Angular won't be able to get that element as it won't be rendered, hence the error that comes up.

One of the solutions is to use a `display: hidden` on the element instead of the `*ngIf` so the element gets rendered but is hidden until your condition is fulfilled.

Read More [over at Github](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-grid/issues/411#issuecomment-236168285)

Comment: What are the other options?

Comment: I'm glad you pointed this out. I don't know if I would have spent a few more hours on trying to figure out how to fix my issue!

Comment: great tip, it helped me, this might be the correct answer in some cases

Answer (score 0):

## remove *ngIf

in my case inside @ViewChild element I was using *ngIf like below.

```
<ul class="menu" *ngIf="isMenuOpen" #menu>
  <li *ngFor="let data of dropdownData" (click)="onClickOfVal(data)">
    {{ data }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

**updated code**

```
<ul class="menu" [style.display]="isMenuOpen ? 'block' : 'none'" #menu>
  <li *ngFor="let data of dropdownData" (click)="onClickOfVal(data)">
    {{ data }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p #contentParagraph>
      <strong *ngIf="serverElement.type === 'server'" style="color: red">{{
        serverElement.content
      }}</strong>
      <em *ngIf="serverElement.type === 'blueprint'">{{
        serverElement.content
      }}</em>
        {{ serverElement.content }}
      </strong>
    </p>
```

When I was using my local reference on ngIf statement it was giving an error cannot read property native element of undefined.

To rectify this problem we have to replace ngIf with any property binding then we can access our nativelement via ViewChild or ContentChild in another component.

```
       <p #contentParagraph> 
       <strong
        [ngStyle]="{
          color: serverElement.type === 'server' ? 'red' : 'blue'
        }"
      >
        {{ serverElement.content }}
      </strong>
    </p>
```

Answer (score -1):

What happens is when these elements are called before the DOM is loaded these kind of errors come up. Always use:

```
 window.onload = function(){
     this.keywordsInput.nativeElement.focus();
 }
```

Answer (score -3):

Initializing the Canvas like below works for TypeScript/Angular solutions.

```
const canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById("htmlElemId"); 

const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Answer (score -5):

it just simple :import this directory

```
import {Component, Directive, Input, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: This is NOT a solution to the problem in the question.