# Can you use @ViewChild() or similar with a router-outlet? How if so?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I repeatedly run into a situation where I'd like to access a child component existing on the other side of a router outlet rather than a selector:

```
Like:
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

NOT:
<selector-name></selector-name>
```

This conflicts with the ViewChild functionality as I know it, yet it seems like my component should be able to see and interact with what's inside that router-outlet just as easily as with what's inside a selector-tag.

For instance I tried this:

```
export class RequestItemCatsComp {
    @ViewChild('child') child: RequestItemsComp;
    ***etc...***
ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.child) // Always child is undefined
        this.groupId = this.child.groupId;
    }
}
```

But naturally, **child is undefined** because this is the wrong way. Is there a right way?

I'm trying to use a service to share the data but then run into another problem "expression has changed after it was checked" which I'm hoping to remedy without a hack or enabling prod mode.

Comment: You can try `@ViewChild(RequestItemsComp) child: RequestItemsComp;`. I wouldn't expect it to work (not tried) but `@ViewChild('child')` only works if the element has a template variable `#child` which is not possible for routed components.

Comment: Use a service to share data between routes. You might be able to work around the "expression has changed after it was checked" error using `setTimeout()`.  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#afterview

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You may tap into activate event to get reference of instantiated component inside the router outlet.

excerpt from [RouterOutlet Docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterOutlet-directive.html#!#activated-anchor)

> A router outlet will emit an activate event any time a new component
>   is being instantiated, and a deactivate event when it is being
>   destroyed.

**example**

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h3 class="title">Basic Angular 2</h3>
  <router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)" ></router-outlet>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(){}

  onActivate(componentRef){
    componentRef.sayhello();
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h3 class="title">Dashboard</h3>
  `
})
export class DashboardComponent {
  constructor(){}

  sayhello(){
    console.log('hello!!');
  }
}
```

Here is the [Plunker!!](https://plnkr.co/edit/cpHn5vhT24EWl4ZuhZwO?p=preview)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Is this good practise? You would have to do extra work to work out which component was activated?

Comment: ideally you would use service to have interaction between components, having said that it depends upon your requirement. Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks. After long search without results about how to build angular2 multi step form wizard based on router-outlet and child pages. This answer was a key principal in my multi-tab form editor where each tab is a separate component/page but all extend a common base. This allowed me to have navigation and submission button around router-outlet and delegate the actual actions to the pages themselves.

Comment: How can i receive a variable this way if variable haven't reach the child component yet? For example in child component you have method getSomething that fired at ngOnInit.

Comment: componentRef is undefined when I try this

Comment: Kudos to you, you just saved me few hours.

Comment: This is strongly discouraged. activate should be used in rare situations when you need to listen to the activation event, or deactivation when it's destroyed, and never for parent-child communication. Use services.

Answer (score 3):

The approach by Madhu works if you are not reattaching to a route. It appears that activate does not get run on the re-route.

There is a read only property on router-outlet that contains the current component.

example:

```html
 @Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h3 class="title">Basic Angular 2</h3>
  <button (click)="identifyYourself()"></button>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild(RouterOutlet) outlet;
  constructor(){}

  identifyYourself() {
    if (outlet && outlet.component) {
      (outlet.component as IIdentify).identify();
    }
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h3 class="title">Dashboard</h3>
  `
})
export class DashboardComponent implements IIdentify{
  constructor(){}

  identify(){
    console.log('Hello, I'm the dashboard!');
  }
}
interface IIdentify {
    identify:()=>void;
}
```

See an example here
Check this example out

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zluvgc

Comment: Hi @TjReinert, what does mean "RouterOutlet" here?

Comment: It wont https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-z1r5yn?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: So the RouterOutlet is going to be where the component associated with the 'ActivatedRoute' is going to be rendered. When there is a component, you will have it under outlet.component. You can then call any method that is on that component. 

In your example it looks like you do not have the idenetifyYourself method on your views.


Here's an example

given your routes
if you were on the 'login' route, then the component would be 'LoginViewComponent'.

Comment: Check this example out. Adding this to my answer

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zluvgc

Comment: I forked but didn't manage to make PR so here updated version with my suggestion. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-glkzhw?embed=1&file=src/app/hello.component.ts