# Angular2 getting data from child route in app-root

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

In my app-root component I have `router-outlet` in container with some styles. 
I have route:

```
{
    path: 'some-path',
    component: ChildContainer,
    data: { variable:'variable' },
}
```

And I can to get variable in ChildContainer, but I need it in AppRoot. So, from [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterState-interface.html) I can get it from `child`, but if I do this in AppRoot constructor:

```
const state: RouterState = router.routerState;
const root: ActivatedRoute = state.root;
const child = root.firstChild;
```

and `console.log(root, child)` - child is null, and root contains correct child (invoke property getter).
So, how can I get `variable` in AppRoot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may tap into activate event to get reference of instantiated component inside the router outlet.

Check This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39255311/can-you-use-viewchild-or-similar-with-a-router-outlet-how-if-so/39255691#39255691)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h3 class="title">Basic Angular 2</h3>
  <router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)" ></router-outlet>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(){}

  onActivate(componentRef){
    componentRef.sayhello();
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h3 class="title">Dashboard</h3>
  `
})
export class DashboardComponent {
  constructor(){}

  sayhello(){
    console.log('hello!!');
  }
}
```

Here is the [Plunker!!](https://plnkr.co/edit/cpHn5vhT24EWl4ZuhZwO?p=preview)

**Update**

expose `ActivatedRoute` as a public property and once you have the routed component reference, subscribe to data,

```
onActivate(componentRef){
    componentRef.route.data.subsribe(data => {
       console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it a little different case. In my, I need to get variable from router data https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html#!#data-anchor

Comment: @qweasd : updated answer based on your comment, Cheers!!