# Access router outlet component from parent

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have the following app root:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    providers: [],
    templateUrl: `<button (click)="callChildFunction()">Close</button>
                  <router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
export class AppComponent {

    constructor() {

    }

    callChildFunction(){
        // Call myFunction() here
    }

}
```

And here is my child (component used in the `router-outlet`):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    providers: [],
    templateUrl: `<div>Hello World</div>`
})
export class ChildComponent {

    constructor() {

    }

    myFunction(){
        console.log('success');
    }

}
```

I have discovered that I can use [RouterOutlet](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet) to get the component functions but it doesn't seem accessible from within the app root.

How can I call `myFunction()` from the app root?

Comment: you just want to call the child function in the the parent component ?

Comment: Exactly... I'd like to get the (not known) component used in the router outlet and call its function

Comment: if you dont know about the component how can you call the method will all the components have a common method?

Comment: Yes, all the components have a common method that does different things based on the component. But the name of the method is always the same...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Make use of `activate` event for the same .
Whenever we load a component in router outlet a activate event is emitted make use of that to get the component ref and call the respective method.

**Parent Component**

```
  <div class="container">
    <router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
  </div>
```

Template

```
  onActivate(componentRef){
    componentRef.works();
  }
```

**Child Comp**

```
 works(){
    console.log("works");
  }
```

Comment: but while initial loading, child component wont get displayed in DOM....sample - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-9vn8zc?file=app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 7):

A small addition to @Rahul Singh great answer:

Make sure you check, which component instance is returned in the
 (staying at Rahul's example)  `onActivate(componentRef)` method,
**and only call `works()`, if that component indeed has such method**.

Example:

```
     onActivate(componentRef){
       if(componentRef instanceof ChildWithWorksMethodComponent){
         componentRef.works();
         return;
         }
         console.log("This is not the ChildWithWorksMethodComponent");
      }
```

Otherwise, every time you navigate to a route, which component doesn't have such method, your console log will be full of errors like:

> ERROR TypeError: componentRef.works is not a function

Comment: It seems as though this works to call functions in the `router-outlet` component, but it doesn't seem to allow for access to `properties`, not even through `getters` and `setters`. So unable to access data/properties in the  `router-outlet` component, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Router-outlet is related to routing it has nothing to do with accessing the child component methods.You have to use @ViewChild for accessing child component functions from the parent.You can find the example [here](http://learnangular2.com/viewChild/)

**update**

If above isn't a feasible solution in your case,you may tap into activate event to get reference of instantiated component inside the router outlet.

From the docs

> A router outlet will emit an activate event any time a new component is being instantiated, and a deactivate event when it is being destroyed.

Hence you can use these feature and get your work done.You can see elaborated answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39255311/can-you-use-viewchild-or-similar-with-a-router-outlet-how-if-so?answertab=active#tab-top) and a plunker is attached in the same answer

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the problem! When I say "child", it means the component in the `router-outlet`! Please, look at the code mentioned in my question

Comment: you want to access myFunction inside AppComponent  right or am i missing something?

Comment: Exactly... and as far as I know, `@ViewChild` is used to access DOM elements of a component!

Comment: ViewChild is used to access a child component. This includes its template AND its methods.

Comment: @LarsMonty What if I don't know which component it is? Should I import all possible components and get the name with `ActivatedRoute`? This doesn't seem very neat...

Answer (score 0):

For more infomation, you can access the variable of ChildComponent as well.

**Child Comp**

```
export class ChildComponent {
    my_var= true;
}
```

**Parent Component**

// Template

```
<div class="container">
    <router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
  </div>


  onActivate(componentRef){
    console.log(componentRef.my_var);
  }
```