# @Output communication between child and parent. Angular 2(5)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to learn angular 2 and am trying to set a variable in a parent component with data from my child components.  Basically I have a subheader in my parent view and I want the title and some HTML to change based on what child is loaded.

Parent component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class ParentComponent {
  childDetails: {title: String, helperBar: String};

  onChildLoaded(childData: {
    childTitle: string,
    childHelperBar: string
  }) {
    this.childDetails ={
      title: childData.childTitle,
      helperBar: childData.childHelperBar
    };
    console.log (childDetails);
  }
}
```

Child Component :

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation, Output, EventEmitter } 
from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-first-child',
  templateUrl: './first-child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./first-child.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class FirstChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() childLoaded = new EventEmitter<{childTitle: string, 
childHelperBar: string}>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.childLoaded.emit({
      childTitle: 'Dashboard',
      childHelperBar: '<div class="test"><button>Dash Button</button>
</div>'
    });
  }

}
```

And finally my parent HTML:

```
<div class="subheader">
  <h1>{{ childDetails.title }}</h1>
  {{ childDetails.helperBar }}
</div>
<nav class="sidebar">

</nav>

<main role="main" class="">
  <router-outlet (childLoaded)="onChildLoaded($event)"></router-outlet>
</main>
```

For the life of me I can't get this approach to work and can't pinpoint where I'm going wrong.  I could always just put the subheader in my children but I dont like the idea of repeating the code so many times and it will make my layout a bit harder to achieve.

Comment: There is no parent-child relation between a component loaded inside a router-outlet and the component that wraps the router. You should use other approach, like a shared service.

Comment: So if for example the <router-outlet> was replaced with <app-first-child> this approach would work?  Obviously not suitable for me, but just to make sure i'm getting it.  Anyway thanks for the input, will go ahead with a service, cheers ;)

Comment: @Cheekumz, best way is using service, but if you want to use router-outlett you are looking for is (activate) event, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39255311/can-you-use-viewchild-or-similar-with-a-router-outlet-how-if-so/39255691#39255691 , Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is making use of the service and  `observable` so that whenever the child component changes, the new data will get immediately reflected in the parent component.

in your service.ts,

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class myService {

  private pageName = new Subject<string>();

  pageNameChange$ = this.pageName.asObservable();
  changedComponentName(option:string){
        this.pageName.next(option);
  }
}
```

In your child components,

child component 1

```
public ngOnInit() {
  this.myService.changedComponentName('child1');
}
```

child component 2

```
public ngOnInit() {
   this.myService.changedComponentName('child2');
}
```

and so on..

Now, to get the changed Component names in your parent component,

parent component.ts

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

export class parentComponent {

    private subscription:Subscription;

    constructor(private myService:myService){

        this.myService.pageNameChange$.subscribe( /* get called on every child page changes*/
         newPageName => {

        console.log(newPageName); // you get your passed component name ( child1 / child2 /etc.. here in the 'newPageName' variable
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting ? `$event` in your parent method?

If YES then why are you using `let childDetails ={}` inside parent class method . Instead you should use `this.childDetails={}`

```
onChildLoaded($event){
 this.childDetails ={ title: $event.childTitle, helperBar: $event.childHelperBar }; 
console.log (childDetails); 
}
```

and parent html shoul be

```
<div class="subheader"> <h1>{{ childDetails.title }}</h1> {{ childDetails.helperBar }} </div> 
<nav class="sidebar"> </nav> 
<main role="main" class="">
 <app-first-child (childLoaded)="onChildLoaded($event)"></app-first-child> </main>
```

If you don't want to use `<app-first-child/>` then you should use shared service

Comment: Sorry that was actually a mistake, I have been using this. in my code.  Have updated my question accordingly. :)