# Angular dynamic child to parent communication

Tags: angular

I'm building an app where a module loads a shared global component, and a router driven child component. When the module loads the child, it should receive data and send it to the global component.

How do I retrieve the data from dynamically loaded children components?

**Global Component:**

Component:

```
export class global__component implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  // bring data from other components
  @Input() pageTitle: string;

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>{{pageTitle}}</p>
```

**Module Component:**

Component:

```
export class parent__component OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  // bring data from other components
  @Input() pageTitle: string;

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<global-component [pageTitle]="pageTitle"></global-component>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**Child Component One:**

Component:

```
export class child_component_one implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  // send data to other components
  @Output() pageTitle: string = 'Child component One title';

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**Child Component Two:**

Component:

```
export class child_component_two implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  // send data to other components
  @Output() pageTitle: string = 'Child component two title';

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Comment: The @Output properties should be EventEmitters that emit the data in response to some trigger like the OnInit lifecycle hook. However, the child components are being loaded into the router outlet so the global component doesn't have access to them so the data needs to be shared via some other means. This could be a shared service like this Angular's TitleService. https://angular.io/guide/set-document-title or you could create your own. You could also bind data to the route and have the child components set the title that way like in this example: https://angular.io/guide/set-document-title.

Answer (score 0):

@Josavish's comment lead me to router searching answers and stumbled upon [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39255311/can-you-use-viewchild-or-similar-with-a-router-outlet-how-if-so) which had the bit of code I needed.

**Parent Component:**

Component:

```
export class parent__component implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  // set default value
  pageTitle: string = '';

  // get data from children components
  setData(data){
    this.pageTitle = data.updateComponentData().pageTitle;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<global-component[pageTitle]="pageTitle"></global-component>
<router-outlet (activate)="setData($event)"></router-outlet>
```

**Child Component:**

Component:

```
export class child__component implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  // set page title
  pageTitle: string = 'Child component title';

  // update parent component data
  updateComponentData(){
    return {
      pageTitle: this.pageTitle
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

Comment: Nice work researching and finding a solution. I've never used the activate event on the router outlet before so I learned something new too.