# Ionic 2 : How do you reinstantiate @ViewChild if you dismiss the view?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, angular2-template

I'm creating a chat experience and the page keeps up with the conversation by using the scrollToBottom method from Content on ionic-angular. If I start at the "PreChat.html" and go to "Chat.html" then I dismiss "Chat.html" to go back to "PreChat.html" and return again to "Chat.html" I get the following error: "Cannot read property 'scrollToBottom' of null". The experience should be able to be entered into at any time or repeatedly.

PreChat.html:

```
<ion-content>
  <button (click)="goToChat()" href="#">
    Chat
  </button>
</ion-content>
```

PreChat.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Chat } from '../chat';

@Component({
  selector: 'preChat',
  templateUrl: 'preChat.html'
})
export class PreChat  {
   constructor(private modalCtrl: ModalController){}

   goToChat(): any {
    let profileModal = this.modalCtrl.create(Chat);
    profileModal.present();
  }
}
```

Chat.html:

```
<ion-content>
  <button ion-button="filter-button"(click)="dismiss()">
    <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  <div *ngFor="let convo of conversationArray">
    <div class="b-text">{{convo.speak}}</div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Chat.ts:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Content, Events, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'Chat.html'
})

export class Chat {
  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
  conversationArray: any[] = [];
  constructor(private events: Events, private viewCtrl: ViewController){
    this.events.subscribe('conversation', convo => {
      this.conversationArray = convo;
      this.content.scrollToBottom();
    })
  }
  dismiss() {
   this.viewCtrl.dismiss(); 
 }
}
```

Comment: Is the id named 'content' provided in html? It needs to be referenced using `#content` and then you can try `this.content.nativeElement.scrollToBottom()`, as it's the native element that you are referring to. For more details check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39158922/viewchild-not-working-cannot-read-property-nativeelement-of-undefined

Comment: @Deepak, why would I need the id when content refers to <ion-content> specifically? http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/content/Content/

Comment: After much searching, there appears to be a way to pass data between components with ViewChild that doesn't quite apply in the context of using ionic/angular Content. Having said that, my purpose was to create a chat based bottom scroll as seen in the Ionic docs. That's way to much code for nothing but bugs and inconsistency. This link provides a much clearer solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/7yz2DUttPjI5GVJkvr5h?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts&p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `ionViewDidEnter` page event instead of the `constructor` for that.

> Runs when the page has fully entered and is now the active page. This
>   event will fire, whether it was the first load or a cached page.

```
ionViewDidEnter() : void {
 this.platform.ready().then(() => { //platform ready
   this.events.subscribe('conversation', convo => {
      this.conversationArray = convo;
      this.content.scrollToBottom();
    })
 })
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but it didn't work. Was there a step or detail missed in using ionViewDidEnter? I'm not familiar with this lifecycle hook specifically. Could have something to do with the Chat.ts and Chat.html being a modal?

Comment: Hmm... This is the doc about life cycle hooks : https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/src/navigation/nav-controller.ts#L238

Comment: I think this issue is with @ViewChild. It needs to get reinstantiated but that's not happening right now. Any thoughts on this nuance?

Comment: What does it show when you put a debug on `content`?

Comment: How do you put a debug on content? As it stands I'm getting content as null.

Comment: Hmm.. Did you try inside this `this.platform.ready().then(() => {})`?

Comment: Yes all of this happens after this.platform.ready() which occurs upon app load in my app.component and preChat is just a tab that gets initialized after this.platform.ready() happens. Are you saying I need to do this.platform.ready() again?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
this.content = this.ViewCtrl.getContent();
```