# mat-checkbox does not properly display checked value

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am using the mat-checkbox component from Angular Material. But when I check on the checkbox, if I reference `event.target.querySelector('input[type=checkbox"]').checked`, it will tell me the value is false, and when I uncheck the checkbox, it will tell me the value is true. It should be the reverse.

Also, if I try to use `ViewChild` with mat-checkbox, it yields undefined. Therefore, I cannot reach the element using `this.el.nativeElement`.

I illustrate the issue with this isolated git repo:

https://github.com/lovefamilychildrenhappiness/AngularMaterialDefaultStyle/commit/4ab86c34adf9ee966981e7ca6afe14ca403fb9c1

Here is some relevant code from the repo:

```
// app.component.ts
@ViewChild('ref', {static: false}) el: ElementRef;

doSomething(e) {
    // this reads false when you check the checkbox and true when you uncheck the check box:
    console.log('checkbox checked? ', e.target.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]').checked);

    // I can't even use ViewChild with mat-checkbox. It is undefined:
    // 'cannot read property nativeElement of undefined'
    console.log('the native element: ', this.el.nativeElement);

  }

 // app.component.html
 <mat-checkbox
 (click)="doSomething($event)"
 >Bladder</mat-checkbox
 >
```

Why does `event.target.querySelector('input[type=checkbox"]').checked` give the wrong value? And why is `this.el` undefined?

Answer (score 1):

with the the latest angular 8.0.0-rc.5, a breaking change was included where `@ViewChild` must define a static option.

In the angular 7 release (7.2.15) this option does not exist, causing a typescript error during compilation.

one workaround is to "cast" the options type to any

```
@ViewChild('ref', {static: false} as any) el: ElementRef;
```

For `this.el` undefined, it can be issue if your target element is inside a hidden element, then don't use `*ngIf`. Instead use a class to show/hide your element being hidden. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39158922/viewchild-not-working-cannot-read-property-nativeelement-of-undefined)

For checked values to see true or false, you can try to use in this way:

```
onChange(item, event) {
  if (event.checked) {            
     // Add checked / true vlaues to array
      this.selectedValues.push((item));
      // use for loop to iterate values to check true or false and perform operations
     }
       else{
        //remove unchecked / false values
        let index = this.selectedValues.indexOf(item);
        this.selectedValues.splice(index, 1);
      }
  }
```

in html:

```
<mat-checkbox (change)="onChange(val1, $event)" [ngModel]="checkedVal">label1</mat-checkbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume click happens before checked value gets updated. Try with (change) event and add #ref to your checkbox

html

```
 <mat-checkbox #ref (change)="doSomething($event)">Bladder</mat-checkbox>
```

ts

```
 doSomething(e) {
   console.log(e.target.checked, this.el.nativeElement);
   // true/false, HTMLInputElement
 }
```

Comment: actually this.el.nativeElement is still undefined. But the change event does pass a mat-specific event I realized.

Comment: Why is this.el.nativeElement still undefined?

Comment: if you create stackblitz i can take a look