# @ViewChild("childRef") childElementRef -- Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to understand how to use ´@ViewChild´ in an Angular app, so I have created two components: **parent** (base) and **child** with the following code:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit  } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-base',
  templateUrl: './base.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./base.component.css']
})
export class BaseComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild("childRef") childElementRef: any;

  childComponentTitle = 'fake child component title';

  constructor(public router: Router) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.childComponentTitle = this.childElementRef.childComponentTitle;
  }

  changeChildComponentTitle() {
    this.childElementRef.changeComponentState('actual child component title');
  }
}
```

---

```
<h1>parent (base) component</h1>

<app-child #childRef></app-child>

<h2>{{ childComponentTitle }}</h2>

<button (click)="changeChildComponentTitle()">Show Real Child Component Title</button>
```

---

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent {

  childComponentTitle: string = "";

  changeComponentState(newState: string) {
    this.childComponentTitle = newState;
  }
}
```

---

```
<h1>child component</h1>

<h2>{{ childComponentTitle }}</h2>
```

---

If I understand it correctly, once I click the button (which is managed by the ´BaseComponent´) it should invoke the ´changeComponentState´ method (which is managed by the ´ChildComponent´) and that should display ´actual child component title´ on the page.

This does happen, but upon the app loading, I immediately get this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'childComponentTitle') at PageoneComponent.ngAfterViewInit
```

Could someone please help me figure out why this error is thrown?

Comment: 1: you should see an error in the console which should help you to find the issue. 2: itseems you don't have `<app-child` rendered inside of your `BaseComponent`

Comment: `childElementRef` is undefined because there's no element matching the `ViewChild` selector. Using `"childRef"` means Angular will search for an element with a template reference `#childRef`, but there isn't one in `BaseComponent`'s template

Comment: Thank you @p4m. I added it. But I still get `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'childComponentTitle')`. Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

You should add an if before trying accessing to the child :

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (this.childElementRef) {
      this.childComponentTitle = this.childElementRef.childComponentTitle;
    }
  }
```

Comment: this doesn't really solve the problem, code will still crash because `childElementRef` is undefined

Comment: Thank you Hamza. Your solution introduces a new error: `ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: fake child component title.`

Comment: Also Hamza, when I add the `if` statement, the `fake child component title` does not display when the app loads.

Comment: `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` is caused because you are updating the childComponentTitle in parent after it was updated in the template.  [Read more about the error](https://indepth.dev/posts/1001/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error)

Answer (score -3):

this solution [using a hidden element...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52540563/3253999) works for me...

My target element was inside a hidden element, because I was using *ngIf. that was the reason @ViewChild will be undefined.

I must change to use  a class to show/hide my element.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!